# ConvertAvroSchema.java - rename avro field - How to set dynamic property in nifi?

Tags: avro, apache-nifi

I am trying to convert an avro object from one schema to another and rename few attributes using NIFI ConvertAvroSchema.

In the documentation,I see notes about renaming attributes using dynamic properties. But I am not sure how to set it up in NIFI.Should these be set under properties as key value pairs?
  "companyName" -> "name"
  "parent.id" -> "parentId"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes dynamic properties mean properties added by the user at runtime using the + icon on the properties tab. That processor says the name of a dynamic property is the field name from the input schema, and the value is the field name from the output schema.